# Does Golang's net.LookupHost() use all DNS servers in "/etc/resolv.conf"?

Tags: linux, go, dns

I have an application, that's written in Go that uses this function and it keeps failing to resolve a DNS name. I can resolve the DNS name on the server just fine using other applications but not the Go-based one that uses this function.

Comment: Try running the app with `GODEBUG=netdns=cgo`

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, "Use the source, Luke". Reading [dnsclient_unix.go](https://golang.org/src/net/dnsclient_unix.go#L179) reveals that it iterates over all configured servers.

But mind the note:

```
// If answer errored for rcodes dnsRcodeSuccess or dnsRcodeNameError,
// it means the response in msg was not useful and trying another
// server probably won't help. Return now in those cases.
// TODO: indicate this in a more obvious way, such as a field on DNSError?
```